# Retrieve corresponding data from firebase when clicking on spinner item in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an applications that maintains all the sales. I have an inventory database in firebase with all the important information like name, price, description etc. 
I have populated a spinner with names of all the products. Now I want to click on a specific item name from the spinner to get the price of that respective product. 
Searched a lot and found nothing useful

My code so far is

```
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();


            for (final DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final String itemName = itemSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);

                items.add(itemName);
            }
                java.util.Collections.sort(items);
                ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Sale.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
                itemAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                itemSpinner.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

                itemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });

                }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

[image: My database structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `onItemSelected()` add this to get each element

```
String selected = items.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
```

you can also make a log to see which element are you clicking

```
Log.e("Clicked:",""+selected);
```

if you are showing your users id in your spinner, you should get that user id inside `onItemSelected()` and then do another query to the database with that userId you selected and query for price for that product

for example, after you get the selected item lets say is your user id

```
 mDatabase.child("inventory").child(selected)..addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

//Get your price from that element

...
```

all complete should be done like this

```
    itemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                          String selected = items.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                          Log.e("Clicked:",""+selected);

                         mDatabase.child("inventory").child(selected).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        //Get your price from that element

        ...
     }

           @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView){

                        }
                    });

.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a pojo as -

```
public class Inventory
{
    private String name;
    private int qty;
    private String price;
    private String desc;

    public Inventory()
    {

    }

    public Inventory(String name, int qty, String price, String desc) {
        this.name = name;
        this.qty = qty;
        this.price = price;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Inventory [name=" + name + ", qty=" + qty + ", price=" + price
                + ", desc=" + desc + "]";
    }
}
```

Then do -

```
final ArrayList<Inventory> items = new ArrayList<Inventory>();
ArrayList<String> listname = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

for (final DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Inventory inv= itemSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
    listname.add(inv.getName());

    items.add(inv);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Sale.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listname);
            itemAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
itemSpinner.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

itemSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String price = items.get(i).getPrice();

     }

     @Override
     public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

     }
 });
```

Comment: The method told by Gaston will require two retrieve operations which will decrease performance. Also when user chooses the name on spinner it will take some time to fetch the data. But in my method it will fetch the data only once and also price will be shown as soon as user selects the name from the spinner.

Comment: Yep both answers are ok :) I just told op to do that way if they want to retrieve all the data from each parent node